# Не понимаю поведение массива в JavaScript функции

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Помогите разобраться, есть функция:

```
// Парсит данные из html таблицы что бы можно было потом
   // передать данные на бекэнд через  API.
   function getCartStrings()
   {
      console.log(outdata);
      var outdata = [];
      outdata.length = 0;
      $('table tbody tr').each(function(){
         let str = {};
         let tr = $(this);
         let td = tr.find('td');
         str['iid'] = parseInt($(td[0]).text());
         str['cid'] = parseInt($(td[2]).text());
         str['fid'] = parseInt($(td[2]).text());
         str['price'] = parseFloat($(td[7]).find('span').text());
         str['amount'] = parseInt($(td[6]).find('.qty-text').val());
         var ln =outdata.push(str);
      })
      console.log(outdata);
      console.log(outdata.length);

      return outdata;
   }
```

На html страничке - таблица с четырьмя строками в ней. Так вот при первом и втором вызове функции она отдает правильный массив. На третьем и последующим вызовах он выдает массив в котором каждый раз на один элемент больше и этот элементы массив ключей с пустыми значениями. Не пойму как такое может быть? На мой взгляд должно быть всегда четыре элемента в массиве. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: количество совпадает с количеством `tr`. Если между вызовами менялась разметка, закономерно поменяется и результат вызова

Comment: Вызове функции `getCartStrings` или вот этой функции `$('table tbody tr').each(function(){`?

Comment: в итоге в массиве  outdata четыре правильных строчки (по кол-ву строк в таблице и строки с ключами и пустыми значениями. Выглядит в консоли так:

Comment: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {iid: 1, cid: 1, fid: 1, price: 1275.5, amount: 2}1: {iid: 1, cid: 1, fid: 1, price: 1275.5, amount: 6}2: {iid: 1, cid: 2, fid: 2, price: 1275.5, amount: 1}3: {iid: 1, cid: 2, fid: 2, price: 1275.5, amount: 1}4: {iid: NaN, cid: NaN, fid: NaN, price: NaN, amount: NaN}5: {iid: NaN, cid: NaN, fid: NaN, price: NaN, amount: NaN}6: {iid: NaN, cid: NaN, fid: NaN, price: NaN, amount: NaN}7: {iid: NaN, cid: NaN, fid: NaN, price: NaN, amount: NaN}length: 8__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Ну запустите функцию в голом `html` файле и увидите что код работает нормально, ваша ошибка в другом, который в вопросе нету.

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощение за суету - вопрос был не в яваскрипте. Я не точно выбирал таблицу на странице (считал что она одна), при этом дебаг панель  yii2  добавляла свою разметку и она считывалась скриптом. Отсюда и возникали анамальные строки. Уточнил селектор и все заработало. Всем спасибо.